# How to restore a VM from disk image qcow2

Tags: linux, virtual-machines, kvm-virtualization

I had a problem with my server and my VPS provider only wanted to give me a backup of the VM disk in qcow2 format, he told me that I should virtualize and mount that and then get my data and take responsibility, now I find that I don't know how I can explore my files in that disk image had in the vm WHM and cpanel I need to recover those files.

Could I use virtualbox in windows or should I mount everything on a linux server, I have a linux VPS or my personal machine that is W
indows, how could I get the data from a cpanel that I had there?

Answer (score 0):

If you can't run your qcow2 image adding as primary disk in a new VM and booting it you could create a new one with your qcow2 image as secondary disk and try to read it installing OS in a primary new virtual disk but you could have reading issues due to compression compatibility unsupported for qcow2 format in virtualbox so you have to convert it from qcow2 to vdi using the following command trough CLI:

qemu-img convert -f qcow2 qcow2_file_name -O vdi vdi_file_name

And then create a new VM in virtualbox with the image converted to vdi format as main disk to boot the new VM with your old VPS Operating system virtual disk gift by your VPS provider of cpanel and converted to vdi format to be used fine with virtualbox

As explained here:

http://www.dark-hamster.com/server/virtualization/use-qcow2-image-virtualbox/

Note: To run the conversion command you need to have installed qemu package where you run the conversion command in a windows or linux machine trough CLI (Command Line Interface)